# In Adobe Omniture DTM's Event Based rule, how do i define the link name inside the custom script

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics

I've created an event based rule inside Adobe DTM that fires whenever '.link-name' is clicked.  However, instead of hard coding the linkName, I want to define it through the custom page code section.  I've tried s.linkName = 'custom name'; but this didn't do anything.
I've tried s.tl(this, 'o', 'custom name') but this fired the event twice.  Is there a way to define just the linkName in the custom page code?  I feel like there should be a way to do this I'm missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are asking:

1) Adobe DTM can pick up dynamic values:

In "Adobe Analytics" Section, set Prop, eVar, or Link Name to:

```
%this.href%
```

There are other dynamic values you can set. Check the DTM Cheat Sheet from this site.

http://jimalytics.com/tag-management/dynamic-tag-manager-dtm-cheat-sheet/

2) You could try setting a Data Element using the satellite.setVar() method inside "Custom Rule Conditions":

```
//Set a value 
var customLink = "www.yourCusomLink.com";

//Set DTM Data Element to that value
_satellite.setVar("Element Name", customLink);

//Inside Custom Rules - the code must return "true" for rule to fire
return true;
```

Set Prop, eVar, or Link Name to:

```
//Adobe Analytics syntax for passing value of custom data element
%Element Name%
```

The rule will fire and pass the custom value inside

Hope this helps!